# BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method App\Product::Category()

Tags: laravel, methods, undefined

When entering `Route::get('product/create', 'ProductController@create')->name('Product.create');` in my URL i get an error

> BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method App\Product::Category()

But the controller still puts data into the database, but does not return 'Succes'

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Category;
use App\Product;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $product = new Product;
        $product->name = 'God of War';
        $product->price = 40;

        $product->save();

        $category = Category::find([3,4]);
        $product->Category()->attach($category);

        return 'Success';
    }
}
```

i can't seem to find the right answer to this. thankyou.

Comment: do you have Category() relationship in Product class ?

Comment: Thanks sir. solved the problem...!